# How to get information about the authorization of creating a new file or modifying a certain file in a specific directory?

Tags: qt, permissions

In my program, the users may choose the directory to save their files or to modify some files in a specific directory. The program should give a warning if the users have no authorization to create a new file or to modify a file.

But I have no idea to implement the function except that I create a testing file. If the QFile::open(...) function returns true, I will understand the current user has access to write.

Is there any better idea to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `QFileSystemModel` class,it has method

```
QFile::Permissions QFileSystemModel::permissions ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
```

Request permissions for dir where you want to create files..

also, there are some tricks about permissions on windows - look into [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfile.html#Permission-enum) - they should be explicitly enabled in your app, and

```
QFile::ReadOwner
QFile::WriteOwner
QFile::ExeOwner
```

corresponds to current user

UPD - there is an easier way - just use

```
QString dirName=<your dir>;
QFileInfo f(dirName);
f.permissions ();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried the tricks which you mentioned, but it returned all the permissions(It must be wrong, because I can't create files in that directory). When I add the "qt_ntfs_permission_lookup" fragment introduced by the doc, the result was lesser than before. It was without "QFile::XXXXGroup" series. I will look into QFileSystemModel. Thank you again.